# Android Studio: Why won't loops work during onClick?

Tags: java, android, loops, while-loop

I'm just trying to make these images rotate for multiple durations, and as far as I know, I need to use a loop. But when testing it out, it only works for one run-through of the loop, as opposed to ten. What am I doing wrong? Also I'm a  beginner, so take it easy on me.

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public void move (View view){
            ImageView thing1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thing1);
            ImageView thing2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thing2);
            int i =0;
            while (i<10) {
                thing1.animate().rotationBy(-45);
                thing2.animate().rotationBy(45);
                i++;
            //Why does it stop here?    
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug at all with say a breakpoint or log statement to see what it's actually doing in there?

Comment: Right, I'll get on that.

Comment: If you call move() from the UI thread, you will probably only see the end result of all the rotations.

Comment: Are you sure that you're seeing only 1 rotation? What if they're too fast because it shouldn't take too long for a processor to loop 10 times through something simple. Use `Log.i("I'm in a loop, yeay: ", "" + i )` and see if it logs only once or 10 times.

Comment: Yeah, it only says that i is 0, and doesn't continue. :l
Edit: whoops, I forgot I changed it to an if statement earlier; changed it back to a while loop and it looks like it's looping, but the animations only happen once. Interesting...

Comment: Ok, I think I see. It looks like when you have two of the same animation types (rotationBy, alpha, translationByX, etc.) it only runs whatever comes last.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is, you want an animation but u only specify movement without time. An animation should be "do X for T amount of time".

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution sort of, thought I'd share it. public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
int i = 0;
int n = 0;


public void move (View view){
    ImageView rightLeg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rightLeg);


    if(n==0) {

            rightLeg.animate().rotationBy(45).setDuration(500).setStartDelay(0);


            n=4;
        }

        if(n==1){

           n=3;

        }
         if(n==2) {

              rightLeg.animate().rotationBy(-90).setDuration(500).setStartDelay(0).translationXBy(30);


              n=1;
    }

         if(n==3){

             rightLeg.animate().rotationBy(90).setDuration(500).setStartDelay(0).translationXBy(30);

            n=2;
            i=0;

        }
        if(n==4){
            n=2;
        }

        i++;
   }
```